# the problem of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can somebody give me the hints to solve them?

1. Is it true that for any (even infinite) set $S$ , there is 
   a larger set $S’$ than $S$ such that there is no 
   bijection between $S$ and $S’$.
2. Let us write $S \le S’$ if there is an injection from $S$ to $S’$.
   For any set $X$ and $Y$, is it always true that 
   one of the following conditions a or b is true ?

   a. $X \le Y$.

   b. $Y \le X$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Hint: there is no injection from the power set of $S$ to $S$.
2. It … depends. In ZF, this is not provable, but in ZFC it is. In fact, this statement is equivalent in ZF to the axiom of choice. As was mentioned elsewhere, two good approaches are the well-ordering theorem (someone else's suggestion) and Tukey's lemma (my suggestion).